# BERT for next sentence prediction

Tags: prediction, bert-language-model, sentence

I am trying to fine tune a Bert model for next sentence prediction using my own dataset but it is not working.
can anybody tell me what should be the structure of my dataset and how can fine tune using hugging face trainer()?

```
def train(bert_model,bert_tokenizer,path,eval_path=None):
    out_dir = "/content/drive/My Drive/next_sentence/"

    training_args = TrainingArguments(output_dir=out_dir,
                                      overwrite_output_dir=True,
                                      num_train_epochs=1,
                                      per_device_train_batch_size=30,
                                      save_steps=100,
                                      save_total_limit=5,
                                      )

    data_collator = DataCollatorForLanguageModeling(tokenizer=bert_tokenizer)
    
      
    trainer = Trainer(
      model=bert_model,
      args=training_args,
      data_collator=data_collator,
      train_dataset="c:/data.txt",
      tokenizer=BertTokenizer)
    
    trainer.train()
    trainer.save_model(out_dir)

import transformers

from torch.nn.functional import softmax

from transformers import BertTokenizer, BertTokenizerFast, BertForNextSentencePrediction,TextDatasetForNextSentencePrediction
import torch

from transformers import Trainer, TrainingArguments
from transformers.data.data_collator import DataCollatorForLanguageModeling

def main():
  bert_tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-cased")
  bert_model = BertForNextSentencePrediction.from_pretrained("bert-base-cased")
  train_data_set_path = "c:/data.txt"
  train(bert_model,BertTokenizer,train_data_set_path)
  #prepare_data_set(bert_tokenizer)
main()
```

Comment: Please share a minimum reproducible example.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 3):

You should create `TextDatasetForNextSentencePrediction` and pass it to the trainer, instead of passing the dataset path.

So you should create `TextDatasetForNextSentencePrediction` dataset into your train function as in the below.

```py
from transformers import TextDatasetForNextSentencePrediction

def train(bert_model, bert_tokenizer, path, eval_path=None):
    out_dir = "/content/drive/My Drive/next_sentence/"

    training_args = TrainingArguments(output_dir=out_dir,
                                      overwrite_output_dir=True,
                                      num_train_epochs=1,
                                      per_device_train_batch_size=30,
                                      save_steps=100,
                                      save_total_limit=5,
                                      )

    data_collator = DataCollatorForLanguageModeling(tokenizer=bert_tokenizer)
    

    train_dataset = TextDatasetForNextSentencePrediction(
        tokenizer = bert_tokenizer,
        file_path = path,
        block_size = 256
    )
      
    trainer = Trainer(
      model=bert_model,
      args=training_args,
      data_collator=data_collator,
      train_dataset=train_dataset,
      tokenizer=BertTokenizer)
    
    trainer.train()
    trainer.save_model(out_dir)
```

Also you should be passing `bert_tokenizer` instead of `BertTokenizer`. trainer and dataset needs pre-trained tokenizer.

So your main function should be like this:

```py
def main():
  bert_tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-cased")
  bert_model = BertForNextSentencePrediction.from_pretrained("bert-base-cased")
  train_data_set_path = "c:/data.txt"
  train(bert_model, bert_tokenizer, train_data_set_path)

main()
```

Comment: Is there a way of applying sequence truncation using your code? To my knowledge, truncation can only be applied by calling the `__call__` or `tokenize` function of the tokenizer. This is however not accessible in your code as its called from `TextDatasetForNextSentencePrediction`.

Comment: Yes you can, you need to configure your tokenizer. Because TextDatasetForNextSentencePrediction is only used creating examples. Once an example of dataset is fetched; it will be tokenized using the tokenizer. Thereby, if you configure the tokenizer for truncation it will truncate the data from dataset

Answer (score 0):

According to [huggingface source code](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/9f72e8f4e1e767c5f608dd135199e592255b8a69/src/transformers/data/datasets/language_modeling.py), the structure of the input dataset needs to be:

> ## Input file format:
>
> ```
>     # (1) One sentence per line. These should ideally be actual sentences, not
>     # entire paragraphs or arbitrary spans of text. (Because we use the
>     # sentence boundaries for the "next sentence prediction" task).
>     # (2) Blank lines between documents. Document boundaries are needed so
>     # that the "next sentence prediction" task doesn't span between documents.
>     #
>     # Example:
>     # I am very happy.
>     # Here is the second sentence.
>     #
>     # A new document.
> ```